# Laravel Date assign errorr

Tags: laravel, date, subscription, status

I have small problem in app. Backend is Laravel and Front end is Nuxtjs.
When User registered on app,then users must be wait antill Administartor approved.
When Admin approved this user we give them 3 months subscription.

In my code this part is not working.

```
$user->activated_at = now();
       $user->activated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i');
```

```
   {
       $user = User::find($id);
       if (is_null($user)) {
           return $this->sendError('admin_messages.user_not_found');
       }
       $user->status = User::ACTIVE;
       $user->activated_at = now();
       $user->activated_at = date('Y-m-d H:i');
       dd($user->activated_at);
       $user->save();
       Mail::to($user->email)->queue(new ApproveNotificationMail($user));
       return $this->sendResponse('admin_messages.user_activated');
   }
```

Comment: not assigning? What error you're getting? BTW, you can simply do ``$user->activated_at = now()`` or ``$user->activated_at = Carbon::now()`` don't forget to import the Carbon facade if you choose the later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mutator in your User model, to force `activated_at` format:

```
public function setActivatedAtAttribute( $value ) {
$this->attributes['activated_at'] = (new Carbon($value))->format('Y-m-d H:i'); 
}
```

You can define a format for date columns using:

```
protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i';
```

Note that you can directly use:

```
$user->activated_at = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   
 $user->activated_at = \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```